Finding which variable is most associated?
I have a set of data relating to a personality construct - (popularity), I have asked participants to give an overall score for personality and then asked them to give scores for other personal characteristics (happiness etc). Each is scored out of 5 on a Likert scale.
What I’d like to do is find out which of the characteristics has the biggest effect in overall personality score. Does anyone have any suggestions how I might do this?

Assuming that all of your items here are supposed to measure in some part one's personality, I'm guessing one of the more straightforward ways is to employ a confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) if you have strong a priori beliefs about what your personality measure is composed of. Suppose for example we have 8 items that all measure anxiety like below...

The items in boxes here, the manifest variables, are the direct measures of anxiety (the Likert scale responses you mention). The circle here, the latent variable, is the trait we are after. The arrows that run from the latent variable "anxiety" to the respective 8 items are the regression paths, or factor loadings. Each factor loading will tell you which indicators are strong than others. If they are standardized, they can tell you how strong each path is in a way that is similarly interpretable to correlations. If we have a path from Item 1 that has a coefficient of $\lambda = .95$ while Item 2 has a coefficient of $\lambda = .01$, then we know that the first item has a substantially stronger association with our anxiety latent variable than the the second item.
A good overview of this subject can be found here. However, I will note that if your measures here are quite different from each other (happiness and popularity don't seem strongly correlated in my opinion), then you may not arrive at an adequate solution for your model and may need to adapt your items accordingly.
